# Scroll to bottom of a modal window in Vue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue calendar inside a modal, and when the calendar appears, I want the window to scroll to the bottom, but I am struggling to implement it.
I cannot share the code for the modal since it's too large, thus I am sharing only the vue component.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Currently I have this: [image]

And this is how I would like it to be: 
[image]

And here is my vue calendar components:

```
<template class="date-picker-addon">
    <div class="date-picker-box">
        <datepicker :placeholder="today" v-on:selected="startDate"></datepicker>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Datepicker from "vuejs-datepicker/dist/vuejs-datepicker.esm.js";
import * as lang from "vuejs-datepicker/src/locale";



    const state = {
        date1: new Date()
    }

  export default {
      components: {
          Datepicker
      },
      data() {
        return {
            today: null,
            format: "d MMMM yyyy",
            disabledDates: {},
            disabledFn: {
                customPredictor(date) {
                    if (date.getDate() % 3 === 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            },
            highlightedFn: {
                customPredictor(date) {
                    if (date.getDate() % 4 === 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighted: {},
            eventMsg: null,
            state: state,
            language: "en",
            languages: lang,
            vModelExample: null,
            changedMonthLog: []
        };
    },
    mounted: function(){
        let today = new Date();
        let dd = today.getDate();
        let mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
        let yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd < 10) {
            dd = `0${dd}`
        };

        if(mm < 10) {
            mm = `0${mm}`
        }; 

        this.today = `${mm}/${dd}/${yyyy}`;
    },
    methods: {
        startDate(value){

            let startDate = new Date(value);
            let dd = startDate.getDate();
            let mm = startDate.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
            let yyyy = startDate.getFullYear();

            if(dd < 10) {
                dd = `0${dd}`
            };

            if(mm < 10) {
                mm = `0${mm}`
            }; 

            startDate = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;
            this.$emit('update', startDate);

      }

  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your custom modal component emits an event:

```
this.$emit('open', true)
```

Add a ref to your modal component and observe the `open` event:

```
<modal @open="handleOpen" ref="myModal">
```

When it opens, scroll to the bottom:

```
handleOpen() {
    this.$refs.myModal.scrollTop = this.$refs.myModal.scrollHeight
}
```

This will only work if the top level element of your `modal` component is the div with the `overflow-y: auto` style.

If that is not the case, move the logic into the modal component and assign the ref to the element that does have the `overflow-y: auto` style.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying pure JS?

```
modal.scrollTop = modal.scrollHeight
```

I'm not sure if it's the best answer but since I came from JQuery and haven't found the usual "easy-to-use" functions in Vue, I usually use pure javascript to implement it (usually wrap it in a mixin e.g. 'domMixins'). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

Put id="SomeName" on scrollable element of Modal (may be full Content)
then add on div class="modal ...... @focus="handleOpenNews"
and add to Methods:

```
handleOpenNews() {
   document.getElementById('SomeName').scrollTo...you needs
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xyz-component id="scroll"></xyz-component>
OR
<div id="scroll"></div>

var elmnt = document.getElementById("scroll");
elmnt.scrollIntoView(true);
```

**OR, you can also use it in a function**

```
<xyz-component id="scroll"></xyz-component>
OR
<div id="scroll"></div>

methods: {
scrollTo() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("scroll");
    elmnt.scrollIntoView(true); // for scrolling top
    elmnt.scrollIntoView(false); // for scrolling bottom
}

<v-btn @click="scrollTo()">Click Button</v-btn>
```